# E is dense in K, and K is compact then

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Since $E$ is dense in $K$, and $K$ is compact, there are finitely many points $x_1,\cdots,x_m \in E$ such that 
$$K\subset V(x_1,\delta)\cup\cdots\cup V(x_m,\delta)$$

I know that $K\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^m V(x_i,\delta),$for $ x_i\in K$ and $K\subset \bar{E}$. So why is the above statement true?  ($V(x,r)$ is the open ball centered at x with radius r.)

Comment: Which statement and what is $\delta$?

Comment: Since E is dense in K, and K is compact, there are finitely many points $x_1,\cdots,x_m$ in E such that 
$$K\in V(x_1,\delta)\cup\cdots\cup V(x_m,\delta)$$

Comment: this is statement

Comment: and we just pick $\delta>0$

Comment: Since it starts with "Since" it looked more like an argument to *show* some (other) statement ...

Comment: What is $V(x_i,\delta)$? Are we in a metric space?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not write the assumption, $V(x_i,\delta)$ is ball which center $x_i$ with radius $\delta$.

Comment: and K in metric space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a finite subcover of $K=\bigcup_{x\in K} V(x,\delta/2)$ and pick points $x_i\in E$ therein.

Comment: But I think we should write $K\subset \bigcup_{x\in K}V(x,\frac{\delta}{2}),$ instead of $K= \bigcup_{x\in K}V(x,\frac{\delta}{2})$.